# How do you turn the infix applicative operator into a prefix function?

Tags: haskell, operators

In the code below, I have modified the first LET statement so that the infix operator  can be written as a prefix function. I'd like to do the same for the applicative operator <*> but have not been able to get it to compile. Where is the correct place to put this operator if you want to treat it as a prefix function?

```
module Main(main) where

import Data.Functor
import Control.Applicative



main = do

   let y = add <$> (Just 1) <*> (Just 2)
   print y


   -- Turn <$> into a prefix operator
   let y = (<$>) add (Just 1) <*> (Just 2)
   print y


   --How do I turn <*> into a prefix operator
   --???


add x y = x + y
```

Comment: `let y = (<*>) ((<$>) add (Just 1)) (Just 2)` but it would be nice if you showed us what you tried so we can explain the problem with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you turned `<$>` into a prefix operator, `<*>` is operating on two arguments. The first is everything to the left of it, `(<$>) add (Just 1)` and the second is everything to the right of it, `(Just 2)`. To call a function `f` with these as the first two arguments, we'd write

```
f ((<$>) add (Just 1)) (Just 2)
```

If we substitute `(<*>)` for `f` we get

```
(<*>) ((<$>) add (Just 1)) (Just 2)
```

#### fmap and liftA2

If you really want to write this without infix notation, first you could notice that `<$>` is just infix `fmap`, so `(<$>) = fmap`.

`liftA2` is exactly this pattern:

```
liftA2 f a b = f <$> a <*> b
```

So you could also write this as

```
liftA2 add (Just 1) (Just 2)
```

Comment: The one thing I did NOT try was putting (*) before ($). The key insight you make (obvious once you make it) is that that <*> is operating on EVERYTHING to its left. Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to mentally add the parens involved:

```
     add <$> Just 1 <*> Just 2
   ≡ (add <$> Just 1) <*> Just 2      -- by left-associativity (infixl 4 <*>, <$>)
   ≡ ((<$>) add (Just 1)) <*> Just 2
   ≡ foo <*> Just 2                   -- let foo = add <$> Just 1
   ≡ (<*>) foo (Just 2)
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly it could be re-written as:

`(<$>) . (<*>) add (Just 1) (Just 2)`

correct?

Comment: @Keynan That wouldn't work since (<*>) expects its first argument to be f (a->b) and add is just (a->b)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: that was directed at Keynan. Sorry for the confusion.